# Jersey 2.0 jars download for non maven users

Tags: web-services, jersey

I am very new to web services. Where I can get Jersey 2.0 jars and I am not Maven user I have added Jersey 1.0 jars but it is giving the error like this:

> de.vogella.jersey.todo

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want the jars? [jersey download](https://jersey.java.net/download.html). here you go, there you can find the last jars. That right now is 2.19. Cheers!